# How do i read from a csv file I created

Tags: python, csv, file, file-io

I'm a self taught programmer and im trying to make a ticketing system in Python with csv. However, the reading function doesn't seem to be working after trying out different solutions.

The output I get is:

```
['Name\tAge\tGender']
[]
['as\t12\tf']
[]
```

The desired output id like to get is:

```
Name Age Gender

Jack 25  Male
```

I've attached the code of this program below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import sys, select, os, csv
from os import system

def option_1():

    with open(input("\nInput file name with .csv extension: "), 'w+') as f:

        people = int(input("\nHow many tickets: "))
        name_l = []
        age_l = []
        sex_l = []  

        for p in range(people):
            name = str(input("\nName: "))
            name_l.append(name)
            age = str(input("\nAge: "))
            age_l.append(age)
            sex = str(input("\nGender: "))
            sex_l.append(sex)

        field_names = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender']

        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = field_names, delimiter = '\t')

        writer.writeheader()

        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')

        for row in [p]:
            writer.writerow([name, age, sex])

def option_2():

    with open(input('Input file name with .csv extension: '), 'a+') as f:
        fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))

        people = int(input("\nHow many tickets: "))
        name_l = []
        age_l = []
        sex_l = []  

        for p in range(people):
            name = str(input("\nName: "))
            name_l.append([name])
            age = int(input("\nAge: "))
            age_l.append([age])
            sex = str(input("\nGender: "))
            sex_l.append([sex])

        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')

        for row in [p]:
            writer.writerow([name, age, sex])

def option_3():

    with open(input("\nInput file name with .csv extension: "), 'r') as f:
        fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
        f_reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in f_reader:
            print(row)


def main():

    system('cls')
    print("\nTicket Booking System\n")
    print("\n1. Ticket Reservation")
    print("\n2. Append to an existing file")
    print("\n3. Read from an existing file")
    print("\n0. Exit Menu")
    print('\n') 

    while True:

        option = int(input("Choose an option: "))
        if option < 0 or option > 3:
            print("Please choose a number according to the menu!")

        else:

            while True:

                if option == 1:
                    system('cls')
                    option_1()
                    user_input=input("\nPress ENTER to return to main menu: \n")
                    if((not user_input) or (int(user_input)<=0)):
                        main()

                elif option == 2:       
                    system('cls')
                    option_2()
                    user_input=input("\nPress ENTER to return to main menu: \n")
                    if((not user_input) or (int(user_input)<=0)):
                        main()

                elif option == 3:       
                    system('cls')
                    option_3()
                    user_input=input("\nPress ENTER to return to main menu: \n")
                    if((not user_input) or (int(user_input)<=0)):
                        main()

                else:
                    exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You should be able to write some code which reproduces the problem in about 5 lines of code. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You're not setting the delimiter (or dialect) in your reader.  How does it know you're using TABs!  That accounts for your lack of field separation.  Not sure on the blank lines, are you adding blanks?

Comment: There are some lines in here that show you don't know what you're doing at all, e.g. `for row in [p]:`. There's also infinite recursion... I'd recommend just sitting back and going through your code thinking what does what and simplifying it. E.g. instead of multiple lists (which you don't use anyway), you should have one list of lists (and use `for row in my_list_of_lists`). Or list of dicts. Because now you use both csv.DictWriter and csv.writer. You should also preferably open file only for the time you're writing stuff to it.

Answer (score 1):

When writing data to the file, you explicitly change the default behavior of the csv writer to use tabs as the field delimiter. A similar instruction should be passed to the reader as well, so it knows how to separate between the values in each row. The output you are seeing is a result of the reader's default behavior - it looks for commas to distinguish between each value, but as it finds none, it treats the entire row as a single value, and includes the tab character (`\t`) as part of the value itself. Instructing the reader to use the same delimiter used for writing the file would allow it to properly parse each field as its own value.
Once the values are properly parsed, you'll notice that the output is still not quite as you desire; the object that is printed in `print(row)` is actually a list of the items in that row, which is why the output you see now is enclosed with square brackets (`[]`) for each printed line. Regardless of how the file is stored, you will need to format the output when printing it as required. There are many ways to do so, following is just one possibility:

```
        f_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
        for row in f_reader:
            print('\t'.join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [csv.reader docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.

So what you are seeing is the expected behavior. You can join the list of strings with `', '.join(row)` if you like.